# Unity 2D addforce with random direction for the object

Tags: c#, object, unity-game-engine, character, rigid-bodies

Please help me guys ! So I`am making a hacky sack game but when i kick the object it just going up with no random direction and force. And I want my character not to hit the object when running and idle I just want the object hit when my character is kicking.

Here is my code for the player force.

```
  if (canSipa == true)
{  
    _pitcha.GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>().AddForce(new Vector2(1000, 5000));
   }
    }
```

and for the object:

```
  private void OnTriggerEnter2D(Collider2D collision)
 {
   if(collision.gameObject.tag == "Player")
  {   
   _player.GetComponent<PlayerManager>().canSipa = true;
   }
 }

     private void OnTriggerExit2D(Collider2D collision)
   {
         if (collision.gameObject.tag == "Player")
    {
     _player.GetComponent<PlayerManager>().canSipa = false ;
       }
   }
```

Comment: Use a random vector?

Answer (score 2):

You can use vector maths to abstract direction and force:

```
Vector2 direction = new Vector2((float)Random.Range(-1000,1000), (float)Random.Range(-1000,1000));

float force = (float)Random.Range(-1000,1000);
pitcha.GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>().AddForce(direction * force);
```

Comment: Going to try it, I will comeback and tell you the result thanks.

Comment: @Mavvvv it's been 4 years, you ever coming back?

Comment: Ok, so I came back... this worked well. Was trying to spawn coins in an explosion like effect, and this worked great... Just changed the 1000's to 10's otherwise the coins flew off the screen faster than I could see them.

Answer (score 0):

That's because in this line you are defining a vector2 with a fixed direction and force:

```
    pitcha.GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>().AddForce(new Vector2(1000, 5000));
```

You can Use Random.Range to create the vector2:

```
     var direction = Random.Range(-1000, 1000); 
     //This way you can go right and left
     var force = Random.Range(3000,5000); 
     //This way you can variate the force
     pitcha.GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>().AddForce(new Vector2(direction,force));
```

Use public floats as the values (maxDirection, minDirection...) so you can change the values when you play. Hope this help.

Comment: Going to try it, I will comeback and tell you the result thanks.